# I suddenly can't access phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Before someone marks as duplicate I've search through Google & Stack those with similar problems and haven't found a solution

I use to be able to access localhost/phpmyadmin without any problems but now for some reason I can't.

[Here's the error that's appearing when I try to input username password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svHcK.png)

It never asked a password before, and I can create database, table etc but now it asks username/password before I can access it.

Here's the code of my config.inc

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'password';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Solutions I've tried through searching stackoverflow

- I've tried changing the auth_type as other's have suggested
- I've tried commenting `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';` & `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`
- I've tried editing the password in config.inc and inputing those on localhost/phpmyadmin and it results in the image link above.
- As someone suggested, clearing the history, cookie, cache of my browser
- Tried accessing the localhost/phpmyadmin through 127.0.0.1/localhost

All these didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Did you try `Username = root` and leave `password` empty? Or if you set a password on the `root` account, use the password

Comment: Yes I've tried it. It doesn't let me log in. Also creating a password for root inside the config.inc and it still won't let me log in

Comment: Did you set a password on the root account?

Comment: What OS you are running? Depending on the OS, mysql may be running on unix socks, not TCP socks. Also look at the error.log, there are useful messages there.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10. There's no password before, I could access localhost/phpmyadmin without any problems but now it asks one. I could run php codes and connect to the database using 'root' and '' as username and password but now it blocks it.